# Retrieving data from server to local return SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I'm using laravel and let say I'm using 2 connection

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'localDatabase'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'mysql_server' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'serverHost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'serverDatabase',
        'username' => 'serverDummy123',
        'password' => 'dummy123',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

and my DB connect to server

```
$dbServer = DB::connection('mysql_server');
```

after that I just want to select data from my localhost database

```
$sql = "select * from localDatabase.users";
echo print_r($dbServer->select($sql));
```

And then I tried to give my localhost DB some privilege

> username : serverDummy123
>
> hostname : serverHost
>
> type : database-specific
>
> privileges : All privileges
>
> grant : yes

But all still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure .env

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=localDatabase
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=
```